My individual coded Word-Press search Plugin is not working
I want the result of the Wordpess search on the homepage to refer exclusively to the post title and the post text and I have written a plugin for this. However, articles also appear in the search results where the search term can only be found in the GUID of the article.
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Search Plugin
Description: Passt die Suchergebnisse so an, dass nur in den Überschriften und im Text von Artikeln gesucht wird.
Version: 1.0
Author: Michael Barth
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Verhindert direkten Zugriff
}

function custom_search_where( $where, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( $wp_query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        // Bereinigen der Sucheingabe
        $search_terms = get_query_var( 's' );
        $search_terms = $wpdb->esc_like( $search_terms );
        $search_terms = '%' . $search_terms . '%';

        // Anpassung der WHERE-Klausel, sodass nur in Titel und Inhalt gesucht wird
        $where = "
            AND (
                ({$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '{$search_terms}')
                OR
                ({$wpdb->posts}.post_content LIKE '{$search_terms}')
            )
            AND ({$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'post' AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish')
        ";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'custom_search_where', 10, 2 );

Wordpress is installed on a domain barth.education. When I search for "Barth", all articles are displayed, even though I have limited the search to titles and text using a plugin. How can I prevent this? I have deactivated all plugins except Elementor, Elementor pro and my custom_search_plugin and don't know any advice.
Many thanks for the help!

I'd use a plugin like Query Monitor to check what the finally executed search query looked like.
